# NGraphics: Is there a way to have round cap on strokes

Tags: xamarin, graphics, xamarin.forms, pen

Hello I am using NGraphics to draw strokes for xamarin form. In Android, I can draw the stroke with round cap enabled so the stroke of the endpoints are round. In NGraphics I still can draw the stroke but the endpoints have corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer: No

The NGraphic's `Pen` Class does not expose items like `StrokeJoins` and `StrokeCaps`.

You could always mod the source code to add those type of properties to the `Pen` Class and set the appropriate platform-dependent items.

i.e. In the Android implimentation, the private `GetPenPaint` method sets up the Android `Paint` object, just need to set the `Paint.StrokeCap` when appropriate:

```
`paint.StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round;`
```

Ref : https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics/blob/master/Platforms/NGraphics.Android/AndroidPlatform.cs#L193

```
Paint GetPenPaint (Pen pen)
{
    var paint = new Paint (PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
    paint.SetStyle (Paint.Style.Stroke);
    paint.SetARGB (pen.Color.A, pen.Color.R, pen.Color.G, pen.Color.B);
    paint.StrokeWidth = (float)pen.Width;

    if (pen.DashPattern != null && pen.DashPattern.Any ()) {
        var dashPathEffect = new DashPathEffect(pen.DashPattern.ToArray(), 0);
        paint.SetPathEffect(dashPathEffect);
    }

    return paint;
}
```

Comment: Thanks your responsed